# Help me understand Euclid's Second Postulate.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, definition

HI I'm using Greensberg book to learn Euclidean Geometry (with an aim to solve problems ranked D4-D6 lvl IMO wise)
I was unable to appreciate the postulate as stated in the book, [ProofWiki's version of postulate was more intuitive](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Euclid%27s_Second_Postulate)

Since the book is going for general using notion of ***congruence*** as seen by the usage of the term in definition of circle of radius OA as set of all points P such that segment OP is ***congruent*** to segment OA

So by that logic, I can define CD as segment with any orientation and not necessarily parallel to AB .

So suppose CD is at obtuse slant to AB (>90 deg slope) then by the postulate I can produce segment BE congruent to CD: Then Here come the problem, it is intuitive to visualize B is ***between*** A and E even though the term is left undefined by the book

But in case where segment BE is congruent to segment CD , thus BE is obtuse to segment AB, then what does notion of **between** or **betweeness** imply in such case?

[ProofWiki states](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Euclid%27s_Second_Postulate) : *A straight line segment can be extended indefinitely to form a straight line.*

But what I interpreted out of postulate as stated in the book(with help of intuition from ProofWiki):

> ***A straight line segment can be extended indefinitely to form a zig-zag straight lines as desired.***

[image]

***Can someone shed light on where are I am going wrong with my interpretation?***

[image]

Comment: "congruent " means "has the same shape and scale" which in the case of a line segment just means "has the same length" - not orientation. For $B$ being "between" $A$ & $E$ I would read that as meaning that a line segment from $A$ to $E$ passes through $B$.

Comment: Marvin Jay Greenberg, [Euclidean and non-euclidean geometries](https://books.google.it/books?id=4uw0dwi7bmQC) ?

Comment: Intuitive though it be, the ProofWiki statement of the postulate is that which was originally written by Euclid (or at least how Thomas L. Heath translated it) "To produce a finite straight line continuously in a straight line". I don't know Greensberg's book so I can't cmment on the direction he comes from here. Can you give some publication details? what its title is, etc. will be good to start with.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA This books, it was recommended by some comment on Math StackEx comment on question good euclidean geometry books which teaches euclidean geometry and neither too advanced(IMO lvl or axiomatization of foundation of geometry) nor too basic as introductory K11 HS: https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometries-development-and-history

Comment: No issue with it... I was only concerned with the spelling "Greensberg".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : If I can have whatever CD I can produce zig-zag lines too right?(I added an image to illustrate my point)

Comment: @PrimeMover I added book link

Comment: @Integral_spirit This does *not* allow you to define a zig-zag. The statement specifically says that "B is **between** A and E" which means that ABE is a **straight line**. Where is the link to the book? Can't find. Best to edit the question and put the full title and publishing information in the body of the question. I don't have the time or the patience to trawl through pages of comments looking for something that may be a link to something.

Answer (score 1):

ProofWiki uses the "common" English translation of Euclid's [Postulate 2](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/bookI.html#posts):

> To produce a finite straight line continuously in a straight line.

This means that the "extension" of the initial segment $AB$ must be done in such a way that the result is again a straight line (segment). Thus, "zig-zag"-ing is avoided.

Is [Greenberg's version (page 15)](https://books.google.it/books?id=uCYPZ4nRqy0C) more intuitive? Maybe.

Is it more precise? I think so.

You have to consider previous terms (page 12): "the second undefined term, 'line' is synonymous with 'straight line'" as well as "between" and "congruent".

From page 73 and on you will find the axioms regarding "between". The basic one is:

> If point $B$ is between points $A$ and $C$, then $A,B,C$ are three distinct points all **lying on the same line** [emphasis added].

Thus, when Greenberg states his version of Postulate 2, he asserts that

> "there exists a unique point $E$ such that $B$ is between $A$ and $E$"

and this amounts to saying that $A,B,E$ are on a **straight** line.